# Realm order ascending by date always fails

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

I'm new to `Realm` and I find it very interesting and already have managed to save and retrieve data. Among with my data that i save, i also save an `NSDate()` so i can sort my results with the logic `LIFO`, that means the last that is saved should be first out to the table view. This is my code!

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let realmaki = try! Realm()

     var eventodos = realmaki.objects(eventsNewSaved2)
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 288.0
 }

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     let realm = try! Realm()
     let eventodoscount = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2).sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true).count
        return eventodoscount
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("savedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! locationEventsTableViewCell
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let eventakiaSaved = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2)
        eventakiaSaved.sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true)
        let task = eventakiaSaved[indexPath.row] as eventsNewSaved2

        cell.eventTitle?.text = "\(task.realmtitle)"
        cell.eventDate.text = "\(task.realmdate)"
        cell.eventAttends.text = "\(task.realmattends)"

        let imageDef : UIImage = UIImage(named: "noimage")!

        if task.realmeventCover == "No Image Available" {

            cell.eventImage.image = imageDef
        } else {
            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

                let realm = try! Realm()
                let eventakiaSaved = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2)
                eventakiaSaved.sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true)
                let task = eventakiaSaved[indexPath.row] as eventsNewSaved2
                    let url = NSURL(string: task.realmeventCover)

                    if url != nil {
                        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            cell.eventImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }

                    } else {
                        cell.eventImage.image = imageDef
                    }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

The variable `realmgettime` is the Date Time object that i save while the user pushes save button in another view.
The table view remains the same even if i set ascending to true or false.
Any idea why not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted(_:, ascending:)` doesn't modify a `Results<T>`. You attempt to sort the results in `tableView(tableView:, cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, but there is no point doing that. Because you ignored the return value.

```
let eventakiaSaved = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2)
eventakiaSaved.sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true)
```

Above code should be like the following:

```
var eventakiaSaved = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2)
var eventakiaSaved = eventakiaSaved.sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true)
```

More better way is chaining method.

```
let eventakiaSaved = realm.objects(eventsNewSaved2)
                          .sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true)
```

Moreover, `Results` instances are live, auto-updating views into the underlying data, which means results never have to be re-fetched.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#auto-updating-results

So you don't need to re-fetch every time for the same query. Keep the results once, just use it everywhere as long as in the same thread.
The recommended way is like the following:

```
...
var eventodos: Results<eventsNewSaved2>? // Keep results as a model
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    eventodos = realm
        .objects(eventsNewSaved2)
        .sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true) // Query only once
}

...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventodoscount?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("savedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! locationEventsTableViewCell

    let task = eventodos[indexPath.row]

    cell.eventTitle?.text = "\(task.realmtitle)"
    cell.eventDate.text = "\(task.realmdate)"
    cell.eventAttends.text = "\(task.realmattends)"

    let imageDef : UIImage = UIImage(named: "noimage")!

    if task.realmeventCover == "No Image Available" {
        cell.eventImage.image = imageDef
    } else {
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            // Need re-fetch because this within sub-thread
            let eventakiaSaved = realm
                .objects(eventsNewSaved2)
                .eventakiaSaved.sorted("realmgettime", ascending: true)

            let task = eventakiaSaved[indexPath.row]
            let url = NSURL(string: task.realmeventCover)

            if url != nil {
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    cell.eventImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            } else {
                cell.eventImage.image = imageDef
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfect although for LIFO sorting i changed `true` to `false`  and it worked. don't understand why though